# Elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir no sound

Tags: audio, release-jolnir, alsa

Just installed Elementary OS 6.1 on my HP x2 Detachable 10-p0XX, everything was working just fine (sound too). After updating all apps from app center and rebooting device, sound got lost. I can see my audio device in alsamixer, it is unmuted, I can control volume using both tray icon and alsamixer, but the speakers don't make a sound.

`cat /proc/asound/cards` gives mi following:

```
 0 [Audio          ]: HdmiLpeAudio - Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
                      Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
 1 [rt5640         ]: SOF - sof-bytcht rt5640
                      HP-HPx2Detachable10_p0XX--827C
```

I've tried reinstalling pulseaudio, setting rt5640 as default by creating /etc/asound.conf. Nothing changed.

Is there a way to fix it without reinstalling system?

[image: Alsamixer]

[image: built-in mixer]

Answer (score 0):

Got it by unmuting DAC MIXL, DAc MIXR, SPOR MIX DAC R1, SPOR MIX DAC L1 for my speakers, and all HP and HPO with Stereo DAC MIXR DAC L1&R1 for my headset using alsamixer.